The review queues should not notify me to review the suggested tag wiki edits unless I get the privilege of it
Sometimes, when I click the review queues, a red dot is shown on the suggested edits review queue.



But when I click on the red dot, it shows me that “This queue has been cleared.”



From my view, there’s still 1 post that needs to review. (Note that the red point won’t disappear until the post is approved/rejected.)



Every time I wait for other users to review that post, I found those posts are actually a tag wiki edits, and I haven’t gotten the review tag wiki edits privilege.
The review queues should not show me a red dot and notify me to review the suggested tag wiki edits, unless I got the privilege for it.

Related: Please don't show the red dot indicator for review items I can't do

IIRC the queries for items in the queue are not cheap to run, performance wise. If they have to take into account the current user those queries might not run at all to completion in a timely matter.
